# DC Motor Overvoltage operation with current regulation

Tags: voltage, dc-motor

I want to drive a DC motor (linear actuator) rated at 12V with a 24V DC supply.
Will using a driver IC that does current regulation (e.g. MP6515) be enough, or would I need additional measures in place? All other components would be properly sized (capacitors, etc.)

[DC Motor Overvoltage Operation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70029/dc-motor-overvoltage-operation) suggests that using 24V instead of 12V would be ok from an insulation perspective, and I know stepper motors in 3D-printer stepper motors are regularly run at voltages much higher than rated.
I'm just unsure if I miss anything that would be different for DC motors.

I don't aim at getting more power or torque, I just want to use existing motors with another power supply needed for different reasons.

Comment: Exactly which "DC motor (linear actuator) rated at 12V" do you have?

Comment: Hi @BruceAbbott, Its a cheap chinese one of course :) js-tgz-u2 12V 50mm 6mm/sec 1500N. There are some others as well, which I cannot get the exact specs of right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on cable capacitance, the driver losses may cause an increase in temperature rise with twice the supply voltage, so heatsinking may need attention.

Otherwise, the  current in the outputs are limited using a
constant off-time control circuitry of 16 us typ.

Thus, depending on the actuator dI/dt=V/L  on-time with this hysteresis, will promote a PWM astable activity.

Comment: Hard working man! :) In supplement to Tony's, besides the mechanical and electrical issues; The control, if you (@TobiM) have any, will likely need to be tuned for the "loop gain" change. First, limit the output, not to overdrive or to burn the coil, and then get into the tuning.

Comment: To clarify: I do not desire to control the motor other than forward, backward, stop. What I'm reading from "will promote a PWM astable activity" is: might work, but no guarantees?

Comment: It is a stable operation but the "astable" varies in frequency slightly as well as duty cycle with changes in On time.

Comment: Sorry, please bear with me: english is not my native language and all EE is self-taught. I understand, if I were to drive the MP6515 with PWM, the final output might be unpredictabe. But will this be of any concern if I only drive it forward, backward, stop? Or do you refer to the duty cycle/on time the driver will implicitly generate to limit the current?

Comment: Hello @TobiM try "@ with the name to signal to a responder. I am not mad at all. Myself suffers from Konglish. And, still, I am surviving. I think Tony will answer better (he is reading the datasheet, h h). For electrical aspects, you need to read the driver, MP6515 (H-birdge?), datasheet. Interpret it in your way, and then ask specific questions to be answered.

Comment: Tobi, you do not need to control it with PWM, that is internally controlled with load by the IC

Comment: @TobiM And, since you are new, don't forget marking Tony for "answered" (that check mark under the counter), and praise for his hard work..

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: ok, thanks, so I had that right. What I'm struggeling with is the last sentence in your answer. I was reading "PWM astable activity" as a concern, but maybe I misunderstood, and this is simply stating what will happen and is the desired outcome? Also, the datasheet mentions the off-time to be 16us, but the minimum on-time tOCPD is only 500ns, wouldn't this be enough to safeguard the motor&circuit?

Comment: THIS IS NORMAL operation for dI= V*dt/L = 24 * 0.5e-6 / L so for 1A max the coil must be L > 12uH which is must be  true for worst case but V is likely to be a smaller change with motion EMF.

Comment: Hi @TonyStewartEE75, thanks again for all your explanations. So I ordered a LCR tester and measured the coil to be around 650 µH. Applying that to the formula for dI I get (24*0,5e-6)/(0.65e-3)=0.018A. So the minimum on-time would only mean a 0.018A current surge, which would give the IC more than enough time to react. Would you say it's safe to try without risking smoke and fire?

Comment: Yes so Iset is your peak limit , this looks like a suitable  24V driver for a 12V actuator.  You can also attach a thermistor and monitor case temp. Rise.

Answer (score 2):

The controller you have chosen to run a brush-style motor uses PWM only for limiting current rather than voltage.  Applying a higher-than-rated voltage to a brush-style motor may cause it to draw excessive current, even when lightly loaded.  In your case, the motor might spin up until it reaches the current limit, where it would remain regardless of load.  Unfortunately, when the motor is lightly loaded, the power is not going to your load so it goes into heat in the motor.

I suggest choosing a controller that provides a speed control-type (voltage) PWM along with the current limit.  If you hard-limit the voltage PWM to 50%, you should be fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. At 12V the actuators draw around 1A, so I guess at 24V I would make the limit at 0.5A. Either way that would be around 12W, and there possibly wont't ever be really light load. Plus, they will only run for about 10-15 seconds in my application, with several minutes at least to cool down. A problem might be, that I want to use the load sensing to simulate end stops. This works perfectly for 12v actuator at 12V supply. Guess I will have to test with 24V. Does not seem as it would immediately explode though :)