# DC Motor control PWM

Tags: motor, dc, pwm, speed, torque

I need to vary the speed of a DC geared motor using software (Raspberry Pi SW GPIO).

The motor is 3 V DC geared micro motor @150 rpm. At 3 V full 'speed' the motor is very powerful for my needs having sufficient torque. However when I change the duty cycle to decrease the speed, then the torque is also reduced (presumably as duty cycle halves voltage).

1. Is there any way to maintain torque via software?
2. If not, then any idea how the Anki Cozmo/Vector robots do this (see [The Best Cozmo Commercials by Anki](https://youtu.be/uMlr-IY_BP4))?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73463/how-to-decrease-the-motor-speed-without-losing-the-maximum-torque

Comment: Not a duplicate