Driving a permanent magnet DC motor with PWM via optocoupler and an N-MOSFET
In a student lab project, we tried to drive a DC motor from FAULHABER Schöneich 2230V024S (148) and a reductor 81:1 22B (298) 2-16V L=35uH,
see the 024S variant in the datasheet, consuming about 600mA at 12V during normal operation (driving a pendulum). We soldered the Schottky diode SB260 (=SR260) 2A/60V directly across the leads of the motor as a flyback bypass.
We use a PWM signal from the uC (Arduino uno) powered through its USB connection to a hub and a Raspberry Pi-3.  This is a very common and largely discussed setup with an N-MOSFET as a low-end switch, and I didn't expect any caveats.  However, since the ground of Pi3+hub+uC is isolated, I decided to add an optocoupler, which seems to be also a very commonly used solution (see the figure below from https://bestengineeringprojects.com/interfacing-optocoupler-with-arduino/, cf EE.SE question MOSFET switch using an optocoupler),

arduino-optocoupler-interfacing-osc-768x435.png
Available also as a breakout board from Robotdyn
with IRF540N (and an external flyback Schottky diode, see its supposed schematics on https://forum.arduino.cc/t/mosfet-power-module-and-optocoupler/508996). We have tried both of them. Our power is taken from a stabilized 12V lab voltage source, and
our R2=R3=R4=1K. As an additional test load, we use a brushless 12V PC fan. In further tests, we replaced the uC with a square signal from a function generator at 470 Hz allowing duty cycles from 15 to 85% (nb: the standard Arduino library call uses a PWM frequency of 490Hz). Our scope is attached at the gate (channel 1) and the drain (channel 2) as shown in the schematics below.
 In all cases, we ended up with similar observations illustrated below.

no load (LED only) PWM-GBF-470-0load.png

resistive load (brushless fan) PWM-gbf-470-Rload.png

resistive + motor PWM-gbf-470-LRload.png

motor only PWM-gbf-470-Lload.png
All works as expected for resistive loads: when the gate is
high (5V), the FET closes (i.e., lets the current flow from its drain to the source), and channel 2 drops to 0 (ground). However, when the motor (= inductive, or more correctly -inertial, see the answers) load is added in parallel, things go south, and driving the motor alone (last picture) turns into a disaster:  For some reason, despite the flyback diode, the voltage at the drain is low as if the FET remained almost totally closed, even when our gate is kept at 0V!? I cannot see exactly why.
With an additional ohmic load (second last figure), the FET appears sort of half-closed. The voltage at the drain (ch 2) during off time also depends on the duty cycle:  (pwm-gbf-470-15duty-Lload.png 15% duty cycle, Vgs=6V, motor only).
The FET appears to open more for shorter cycles as if something gets saturated during longer cycles (the two last plots differ in their duty cycles).
Question(s):

Explain this circuit and the case of the function generator (Note 1).

Suspecting that what we have is not a bug but a feature, i.e., this is how things are supposed to run, how can we achieve our goal of controlling the speed of that motor in a most simple and adequate fashion? Can our setup be salvaged somehow through some few additional elements or another circuit/strategy imposed?


In this context, let me recapitulate our situation:

we want to use our uC (Arduino) for one-directional speed control of a small classic permanent magnet DC motor operating between 0 (preferably, or 5) and 12V (optionally, up to 15) and consuming around 100-500mA.

The motor is almost freewheeling unopposed, i.e., mechanical resistance (load) is very low, and braking, if necessary, should occur through other means.

Furthermore, while the 81:1 gearbox reduces the speeds to around 50 rpm, the motor itself runs at 4000 and has significant kinetic energy and back-EMF.

uC-wise, the most direct and frequently used output at our disposal is the 5V PWM with frequencies from about 500 and up to 10kHz and 8-10 bit duty cycle
resolutions.

thinking of potential future use of these setups by students, we prefer to isolate the signal side (uC and computer) through an optocoupler.

for the same reason, despite that in the lab, we do have easy access to stabilized positive and negative rail DC power, we like to keep the supply as simple as a small 12-24V 2A DC adapter.

we are, obviously, not electrical/electronic engineers ...



Note 1: The motor+diode can be driven happily with a 470Hz PWM Vpp=10V signal supplied directly from the amplified function generator without any intermediate circuit.  Also, we tried the circuit at higher PWM frequencies with similar results, but the capacitance of the optocoupler or gate (? visible in the pictures, channel 1) becomes more of an issue in that case. In view of the answer by @Bravale, the following test may be interesting.pwm-gbf-470-Lload-GBF-circuit.png. Here we added a benchtop amperemeter in the true-rms AC mode with shunt resistance of about 0.1 to 10 Ohm between the motor and the ground. The impedance of the function generator amplifier is 1 Ohm; the DMM reading is around 80mA. Unlike in the MOSFET circuit, the motor here remains connected to the mains for all times, and the current (Ch 2) flows during both the duty cycle (+10V on Ch 1) and the "off-duty" period (0V on Ch 1). In the latter case, the EMF from the motor (see @Bravale's answer) seem to discharge in the amplifier?
Note 2: Taking another motor+reductor of the same model, connecting the digital multimeter (DMM) to that motor's leads, and turning it by hand, we can observe EMFs of +/- 5 to 7V DC, depending on the rotation sense and speed. Both senses feel similarly. This seems to agree with the datasheet: that motor alone does max 8000rpm at 24V which is reduced to 100rpm. Our motor is equipped additionally with the snubber diode soldered across its leads. That makes directions (and leads) differ: with DMM's COM at the anode of the snubber ("anode lead"), turning in one direction is easy and produces +5..7V, while the opposite direction is sensibly impeded and produces -100..-300mV. The latter seems to be the voltage drop on the SR260 diode: according to its datasheet, its max forward voltage drop can be 0.7V at 2A, suggesting 200mV at 600mA, which is the typical current that we observe when running this motor+reductor at ~50rpm (so that the motor itself does 4000rpm). The motor is connected to our circuit (in parallel with the LED in the drawing) so that the "anode lead" is at the drain (channel 2 point) and the "cathode lead" is at the Vin=+12V. The "easy" direction of rotation, is the direction in which the motor normally turns when powered up (through PWM, when the FET closes).
Note 3: Following the advice by @D.A.S., we raised the voltage at the gate (Vgs) to 10V by putting R3=1k and R2=220ohm. This, however, seems to produce little difference, from the plot below to the last one before notes. (15% duty cycle, motor only *73duty10V-Lload.png). The phenomenon of the FET appearing more fully "closed" for longer duty cycles persists: (33% duty cycle, motor only *33duty10V-Lload.png)  (73% duty cycle, motor only *73duty10V-Lload.png)

Did you mean "FET keeps CLOSED even when our gate is kept at 0V!  was it running full speed no-load with back EMF on drain?

Disable the PWM, rotate the motor by hand and watch the drain voltage.

to @D.A.S. : yes, sorry. I think of FETs as if they were valves, i.e., I say open when it connects its drain to source and lets the current flow through it. From your comment, I understand that the common thinking of FETs is rather that they work as switches, i.e., they should be CLOSED to let the current flow. So basically, we both call the same thing the opposite ways. If my terminology is so misleading, please let me know, I'll edit the post.

Yes this is not plumbing, so it ought to be corrected. It's an electrical switch.  I assume the motor is connected across the LED load and not to 0V which would cause your disable failure.  All transistor switches are inverting from In to Out and MOSFETS need a Vgs = 2 to 2.5 times the Vgs(th) turn off threshold. to reach rated current for low loss. (Vds*Id=Pd)

to @D.A.S. : Ok, corrected that. Sorry again. I'm no good at plumbing either, I teach theoretical physics...

to @D.A.S. : most of the mechanical load on the motor seems to come from the 81:1 reductor, which is factory fitted and is difficult to be taken off. So removing the shaft connection to the pendulum and letting the motor turn "freely" didn't bring any visible changes (last fig). nb: The only other thing that can be dislodged is a small flywheel, but it seems to have insufficient inertia to play any important role at typical rotational frequencies of 50-100 rpm that we use. Its purpose seems to be limited to providing the leverage to the shaft which is attached to it.

to @Jens :  I have added an explanation of testing the motor "by hand" in Note 2. What I describe (for the disconnected motor) agrees with what I understand about flyback diodes. Please let me know if smth seems wrong. If you actually suggest testing the motor connected into the circuit (without PWM and Vin), please let me know. We can arrange for a steady "by hand" rotation using another motor and try to see smth on channel 2 or with a dmm.

Welcome! Please show a schematic with your motor and flyback diode. Refer to schematic node names for your oscillograms.

Where is the motor datasheet?  Also std Vt=2~4V  FET needs 10V on gate not 5 so bypass R2 !! You made an improper substitution. with R2 = 1k

Check your FET connections ,something looks backwards

to @winny : I have added our schematics to the post. It shows how the motor and other loads are connected. Hope this is clear enough

to @D.A.S. : yes the motor is connected across the LED+R4, as described in detail in my previous comment. I have added our schematics to the post. It shows how we connect the motor and other loads. Hope this is now clear enough. Likewise we insert the additional ohmic load (the brushless fan). The ref to the motor datasheet is the 2nd pdf url at the beginning of the post. That pdf covers several variants, you should look for 024S. I'll try to edit it to make this clearer.

You may be exceeding rms ripple current in the fan's input  ecap when you get to full PWM.

Does it still work with a sig gen?  You are using a rated 28A FET on a rated 180 mA FET with a start current of 24 V/50 Ohms = 0.5A. This raises the capacitance in the switch so turning off is slow. But still weird.  With clamp diode expect 500V potential spikes that may induce damage, although this is a rugged chip with a tiny motor.

It will work better with an NPN or a new lower current FET.  ( prev. comment meant 180 mA micromotor)

to @D.A.S. : actually, it is IRFIZ44N with similar characteristics (31A, 55V) to IRF540N in the schematics. The latter is used in the Robotdyn breakboard that we tried at first (url in the post). Originally, we aimed at 24V (nominal motor voltage, 9000rpm) and 650mA max current indicated on our student lab device by its manufacturer. This explains resistor choices. However, the natural period of the pendulum is 1.86sec, or mere 32rpm (after 81:1 geared reductor => 2613rpm on the rotor), or around 7-8V, and we settled on 12V.

to @D.A.S. : you are right looking for various flaws in the design. They sure are there (being no experts, we just started with what I saw on the net), but none seems to be crucial, as the circuit does function fine under other loads, replicating the commercial breakboard behaviour and thus excluding silly errors. So it seems that we may deal with smth else. Have you seen the answer by Brawale? It does explain to me most of our observations, including the dependence on the duty cycle length. Basically, PWM fails on motors turning fast and having a lot of inertia?

With low Vgs, the FET may rise in resistance higher than that of the motor DCR. So the leading edge switches full voltage and as the motor integrates voltage to current the BEMF also feeds back to lower the drive level.  Make sense. Did you remember about R1 and raising Vgs?  Normally Opto drivers work better as switches using a common emitter/source than a common collector/drain.

to @D.A.S. : I have raised Vgs to 10V as you suggested, see Note 3 in the newly edited post and new figures. This shows little change, albeit the trace at the gate (ch 1) becoming sharper rectangles. Unfortunately I didn't have time to experiment with driving directly by the function generator. this has to wait until the next week.

to @D.A.S. : I have investigated how the signal generator drives that motor with pwm. Please see the revised Note 1 in the post and the newly added scope trace there, showing the currents in that circuit.

Your circuit is able to switch load current on and off very well, since the MOSFET is behaving like an open or closed switch. If you were to plot current \$I_L\$ through the load, be it a motor, a LED or a resistor, that plot would show a nice clean zero-level, alternating between 0A and some maximum.
This does not necessarily mean that load voltage \$V_L\$ would also be clean and rectangular, alternating between 0V and +12V, though. \$V_L\$ across a resistive load \$R\$ would indeed appear rectangular, oscillating between 0V and +12V, because \$V_L=I_LR\$. For a resistor, you would expect that when current is cut off (MOSFET off) then \$I_L=0A\$ and so \$V_L=0V\$.
I should point out that what you are measuring on your 'scope is drain potential \$V_D\$ where:
$$ V_D=(+12V) - V_L $$
Voltage across a motor is a different story, because it is rotating and generating an EMF \$V_L\$ roughly proportional to its angular velocity, even though current \$I_L\$ is zero. This is manifest in your plots as \$V_D\$ failing to rise to the full +12V when the MOSFET is off, and \$I_L\$ is zero.
With certain loads, such as a motor, you must not assume that if \$I_L\$ is zero, then so must \$V_L\$ be zero. Clearly that is not the case for a motor. The assumption is only true with resistive loads, whose \$V_L\$ is directly proportional to \$I_L\$.
There remains the question of why the "amplified function generator" does produce \$V_D=+12V\$ (corresponding to \$V_L=0V\$), while your simple MOSFET switch does not. This can be explained by comparing your MOSFET switch with a simplified version of the function generator's output system. This is how the MOSFET behaves:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here, the MOSFET is SW1, and is only able to sink current to ground via the load, when SW1 is closed. It is able to produce the condition \$V_D=0\$, but when SW1 is open, that MOSFET has no control over the potential at D. Contrast this with a naive representation of how the function generator behaves:

simulate this circuit
The function generator has what is known as a "push-pull" output. Like the single-switch MOSFET arrangement, it is able to sink current through SW1 to ground via the load, effectively "pulling current" from the load. Crucially, though, it is also able to source current to the load, via SW2, effectively "pushing" current into that load. This extra current sourcing  ability gives it control of \$V_D\$ at all times, and can enforce both conditions \$V_D=0V\$ or \$V_D=+12V\$.
Using such a push-pull drive, I would expect \$V_D\$ to oscillate between 0V and +12V with any type of load, motor or resistance, because control of \$V_D\$ is never relinquished.
I called the above representation "naive" because the function generator does not employ switches. Rather, it has an analogue output stage consisting of transistors operating in a linear fashion, able to produce sinusoidal or triangular or even arbitrary output waveforms. In this application, though, where you are asking the function generator to produce a rectangular 0V or +12V waveform, my switch analogy above is a close enough representation of what's happening.
That's not to say that the waveform will be a pristine rectangle, the function generator is still fighting against a source of energy in both states, and who "wins" in the battle for control of \$V_D\$ will depend on which is "stronger", having the lowest source impedance, and which is able to respond more quickly to changes.

There is another quirk of behaviour for a push-pull drive that distinguishes it from a single-MOSFET arrangement. In the single switch/MOSFET scenario, when the MOSFET is off (SW1 open), the motor is effectively disconnected at one end, and is permitted to free-wheel under its own momentum.
In the push-pull arrangement of your function generator, when its output is \$V_D=+12V\$ (SW2 closed, SW1 open, above right) the motor is effectively short-circuited, having +12V applied somewhat brutally at both ends, for a potential difference \$V_L=0V\$. In this state the motor's kinetic energy is being drained rapidly (energy lost as heat in its own internal resistance), and the motor experiences hard braking. Therefore, with push-pull PWM, the motor alternates between phases of active acceleration and active deceleration.
In your own circuit, the motor is actively accelerated, but the only cause for deceleration is friction.
This has interesting consequences for motor speed control, in a closed loop. A mechanically unloaded motor will accelerate very rapidly, even at low PWM duty-cycle, and without any means to actively decelerate it (such as you have when using push-pull), it is disturbingly easy for motor speed to overshoot, and take an age to slow down to the desired set-point speed. This is an argument in favour of a push-pull driver, mostly referred to as a "half-bridge".

to @SimonFitch : thank you for your answer. You may see from my Note 1 that I have anticipated it (saying that in the case of the sig. gen. the motor stays connected to the mains at all times) but needed more time to arrive at the same explanation that you give, and so waited timidly for expert's opinion. I plan to edit Note 1 to make more explicit references to the answers.

to @SimonFitch : with explaining what goes on out of the way, could you advice on what we should actually do to control that motor's speed? I have added this to the post as a Question section before Note 1. In particular, could we add a capacitor to store and recycle that braking energy from back-EMF. a bit like in a buck-boost converter?

@Dimitri For one-directional control, the single MOSFET is fine, but the motor can free-wheel, and you have no braking ability. Typically PWM frequency for motors is kept in the low kilohertz or lower. 470Hz is fine. Higher than 1kHz is not advised when using opto-coupler, because opto-coupler transistor switch-off time can be significantly longer than shortest PWM pulse. Short PWM pulses are somewhat elongated, diminsihing control at low duty-cycle. Any capacitance anywhere will further reduce PWM precision.

@Dimitri For braking, you need a half-bridge, consisting of two MOSFETs. If you don't mitigate shoot-through yourself, a half-bridge gate driver IC is recommended. Consider an IC with gate driver and MOSFETs built-in, to handle everything. You can still free-wheel, you don't have to switch either MOSFET "on", but such control requires at least two digital control signals. For instance, one for speed/braking PWM, the other to "disable" the half-bridge to allow free-wheeling.

@Dimitri Even the ancient L293D can do this. There are more modern alternatives (such as DRV8906), but you should at least explore the half-bridge option, or even full H-bridge (also possible with the L293D).

to @SimonFitch : thank you very much for your advice. An old L293d for an old-style DC motor + a good old L7805 for L293d signal entries seem a perfect match. Btw, it seems from the datasheet that L293 use the "old" push-pull transistor amp schematics that you describe in your answer, and that makes it similar to how the signal generator operates.

to @SimonFitch : Encouraged by ubiquitous tutos on how easy arduinos drive DC motors through a single MOSFET, I haven't checked on specialized IC's and breakboards. I assumed that their sophistication served primarily for bidirectional and precise position controlling. And we didn't have them at hand anyway. A fable excuse from a theoretical physicist for not doing enough his homework in electrical engineering...

@Dimitri All IC based push-pull drivers have an enable pin that you can use to switch off both transistors, or independent control of each, so you can still freewheel. In my experience, the challenge is mostly writing the software correctly, and tuning the control loop.

to @SimonFitch : thank you for your explanations. Figures 9 and 10 + tables 2 and 3 in the datasheet provide enough details. Our application does not actually require freewheeling: the motor drives a disk pendulum through a delicate spiral spring, a bit like in an old mechanical watch. When the motor is brought to a halt, we observe free pendulum oscillations at natural frequency. The 1:81 gear reductor excludes any return feedback action on the motor. I expect the L293d to arrive next week, and will let you know of how it worked.

You must take in account that a DC motor running, will generate a EMF in their terminals. A simple model of this motor could be a armature resistance, armature inductance and voltage (EMF) that is proportional to speed.
With "resistive" load (LED) , you see that everything matches in the oscilloscope. A brushless fan will have some electronics to turn DC into AC for the motor, it is not a resistance, but we  can guess current will increase when voltage rises.

When you connect the DC motor, when the MOSFET switches off, the motor is running and will generate a voltage (value  will depend on speed). That voltage will not be clamped by the flywheel diode, because it is the same polarity than mains voltage. The diode will only clamp the inductance spike. What you measure in Vd is 12 V-(EMF - voltage drop), you are feeding the LED and the fan (so voltage drop will be some amount).

In the last shot, as the fan is not connected, the voltage drop will be lower, and you can see more EMF voltage from the motor.

EDIT Note 1.
The current in low-side FET will only flow when FET is activated. But if you measure the current on one terminal of the motor, with a load connected, you can see that when FET is off, current will change polarity and will feed the load. See simulation with EMF=10 V and load 60 Ohm, current through R3 is shown.
With a wave generator will happen the same, the output will be forced to ground and current will flow from motor (generator).


Thank you. This is the explanation that I was slowly coming up with, influenced by some of the comments (notably by @Jens). The way I understand you, is that these motors, more specifically, their rotors, have mechanical inertia in addition to inductance and (small) ohmic resistance. In fact, their principle exploits inertia for pole commutation. It seems also that the 81:1 reductor fitted to our motor works towards increasing significantly its inertia. The phenomenon depends on speed: at small duty cycles, when the rotation is slow,  that EMF is smaller and all looks "better"!

to @Bravale : Thinking of your explanation, I have tried to understand why the function generator (through its amplifier) is able to regulate motor speeds with pwm. This resulted in the additional test described in the newly expanded Note 1. Can you comment on that figure in light of your EMF explanations? In particular, why is the current through the ammeter to ground negative during off-duty periods?

to @Bravale : thank you for your answer. You may see from my Note 1 that I have anticipated it (saying that in the case of the sig. gen. the motor stays connected to the mains at all times) but needed more time to arrive at the same explanation that you gave, and so waited timidly for expert's opinion. I plan to edit Note 1 to make references to the answers.

to @Bravale : with explaining what goes on out of the way, could you advice on what we should actually do to control that motor's speed? I have added this to the post as a Question section before Note 1. In particular, could we add a capacitor to store and recycle that braking energy from back-EMF. a bit like in a buck-boost converter?

The results look normal for an SPST PWM switch to a DC motor.
If the driver were complementary it would perform better with a bipolar Nch or complementary Pch/Nch switches just as the signal generator with 50 Ohms is bipolar, and with Rs=50 limits torque from the current limit.  An Electronic Motor Controller (EMC) would have an Rs much less than the DCR coil resistance of the motor so that it operates with a low temp rise.
It looks normal because when the switch opens, the current stops flowing, and the motor begins to coast. First, the back EMF is generated V=LdI/dt and then I*Rs drop is eliminated since I goes to 0, so V(switch) rises a bit after the exponential inductive flyback decay. If a slow trace was taken, you would see the RPM slow down and the BEMF decrease proportionally depending on the motor drag/load.
Added:
That's better, for Rs=1 from the sig gen to a linear amplifier and  DCR of motor = TBD ,  the transfer function near 0 RPM for motor Vm and source Vs, voltages  is \$\dfrac{Vm}{Vs} =\dfrac{DCR}{DCR+R_{dsOn}+ Rs}\$
Then the impedance of coil \$sL\$ is added with BEMF = -RPM/RPMmax x  +V  and \$I_{start} = +V/(R_s+R_{dsOn} + DCR) \$
Please verify yourself;    No load current = ~ 1% of start current ~10% of rated current.
But with an open FET switch, you are current-limited due to the open switch resistance and the duty factor of RdsOn & DCR.

to @D.A.S. : thank you. I'm glad that we all have arrived at the same explanation.
Now, with explaining what goes on out of the way, could you advice on what we should actually do to control that motor's speed? I have added this question to the post in a section before Note 1. In particular, could we add a capacitor to store and recycle that braking energy from back-EMF. Thinking naively of a buck-boost converter analogy (cf https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56170/why-should-i-worry-about-a-motor-causing-my-supply-voltage-to-shoot-up-when-the)?

to @D.A.S. : check Note 1. we use not the standard 50 ohm output from that function generator but the amplified signal with impedance 1 ohm. so the result should be similar to a half-bridge motor driver allowing active braking.

yes  but Rs should be << DCR  also never use PWM on a BLDC fan as this stresses the Cap inside.
